# Generate option select on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="gameid">
     //<option is a number 1-999>
</select>

<select id="netid">
     //<option is a number 1-999>
</select>

<select id="camp_id">
 <script>
 var a = $("#gameid").val(); 
 var b = $("#netid").val(); 
 var c = a+b; 

 for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++)
    {
        document.write("<option value='"+c+i+"'>"+c+i+"</option>");
    }
 </script>
</select>
```

The code above is to generate some options into selection.

What I want to do there is, if the val in the #gameid is changed, the option list will change too, and so does for the #netid.

However, the option doesn't change. It stay in the default value of the #gameid and #netid.

I don't know what I am missing here. I need a help, please.

**[UPDATE]**

This code almost work. However, when I do the second change on the #cameid after all I have been select, it doesn't change the #campid selection anymore. It will do change it again if I do the change too on the #netid.

```
$("#gameid" && "#netid").on('change', function(){
   a = $("#gameid").val(), 
   b = $("#netid").val(),
   c = a+b; 
   $("#camp_id").empty();

   for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++){
    $("#camp_id").append("<option value='"+(c+i)+"'>"+(c+i)+"</option>");
   }   
});
```

Comment: what are gameid and netid, are they input or select box? please share some relevant html code too

Comment: They are select option too.

Comment: what do u mean, @iyal?

Comment: Why don't you use change event of #GameId?

Comment: c = paresInt(a)+parseInt(b)

Comment: there is no problem with c?

Comment: What is the id of the option you are trying to change?

Comment: Show html content of your select box. as @madalinivascu suggested. It might be possible you had put options value as string literals . and of course you have to use onchange event

Comment: you need to use a onchange event

Comment: I added some html code.

Comment: @madalinivascu, can you show me how to use onchange event on that document.write, please?

Answer (score 2):

Use change event

```
   $('#gameid,#netid').on('change',function (){
var a = $("#gameid").val(); 
var b = $("#netid").val(); 
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
var c = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);

if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'gameid') {
    $el = $("#netid");} else {$el = $("#gameid")};
 $el.text('');
for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++)
    {
        $el.append("<option value='"+(c+i)+"'>"+(c+i)+"</option>");
    }
});
```

note: I used jquery, jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1zgre9pw/4/

Comment: it works to change the value, however it only prints the option value and all of my html code is gone?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
var options = ''; 
for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++)
{
  options += "<option value='"+c+i+"'>"+c+i+"</option>";
}
document.getElementById('camp_id').innerHTML = options;
```

Use similar to insert options to other select boxes if needed

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add Jquery library,

```
 <select id="gameid" onchange="generateOptions();">
    <!-- Your Options --> 
 </select>

 <select id="netid" onchange="generateOptions();">
 <!-- Your Options -->
 </select>

 <select id="camp_id">

 </select>


  <script type="text/javascript">
 var a,b,c,str="";



    function generateOptions()
    {
      a = $("#gameid").val(); 
       b = $("#netid").val(); 
       c = a+b; 
      for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++)
       {
        str= str + "<option value='"+c+i+"'>"+c+i+"</option>";
       } 
      $('#camp_id').html(str); 
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var a = $("#gameid").val(),
 b = $("#netid").val(),
 c;

$("#gameid").change(function(){
   a = $(this).val();  
   c = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b); 
   $("#camp_id").empty();

   for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++){
   $("#camp_id").append("<option value='"+(c+i)+"'>"+(c+i)+"</option>");
   }   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/j9toh39c/

Comment: this one almost achieve what I want. However, it doesn't change/add the value of `var b` when it is changed.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to add options to HTML `select` dynamically. I have tried to achieve the same using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) i.e. to be call on `$('#gameid').populate();`.

Firstly, Add jquery library in `<head>` of page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/QgCqE/12/)

```
$.fn.populate = function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    for (var i = 1; i<=999; i++){
        $this.append("<option value='"+(c+i)+"'>"+(c+i)+"</option>");
    }
}    
$('#gameid').populate();
```

You can add same for second `select`(drop-down) as well.